# how do I create a formula to find percentile of data in different ranges and worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 3 worksheets with data in column Q and I want to calculate the 90th percentile of all the data.  The number of rows of data in each worksheet is different.  It's probably easier to create a helper sheet, but I thought I would ask.

Thank you

Sheet 1 - Q3:q6284
Sheet 2 - Q3:Q10875
Sheet 3 - Q3:Q2812

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for this:

[PERCENTILE](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/percentiles-quartiles.html)([Sheet 1:Sheet 3!Q1:Q10875](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-3-D-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-6a9cc847-547f-40e0-924a-b2ed54cc79a2), .9)

Comment: When I used that function, I received a message that there are too many arguments for this function.  I suspect it's because I'm isolating the specific range for each sheet.

Comment: This is the formula =percentile('2014 Code3'!Q41:Q6322,'2014 Code4'!Q41:Q10913,'2014 Code6'!Q41:Q2850).0.9).  The worksheets are not in consecutive order, there are sheets between the ones that I want the percentile from.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Excel 2010 or later, try:

`=AGGREGATE(16,6,CHOOSE({1,2,3},Sheet1!Q3:Q6284,Sheet2!Q3:Q10875,Sheet3!Q3:Q2812),0.9)`

Regards